# How to open a new html file inside JS with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I'm trying to add a button that redirects to a new page called "app.html" which is part of my project, but I haven't been able to do it since no matter what I do I always get something unexpected.
I read that `a` tags are quite weirs when using webpack, so I added the necessary lines (according to what I've seen online) to the webpack config file like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        home: "./src/index.js",
        app: "./src/pages/app.js",
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        clean: true,
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        },
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "svg-url-loader",
                        options: {
                            limit: 10000,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: "html-loader",
                options: {
                    sources: {
                        list: [
                            "...",
                            {
                                tag: "a",
                                attribute: "href",
                                type: "src",
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "index.html",
            template: "src/views/index.html",
            chunks: ["home"],
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "app.html",
            template: "src/views/app.html",
            chunks: ["app"],
        }),
    ],
};
```

I added the `options` arguments to include `a` tags correctly. However, in my `home.js` file I imported the html file I want to redirect the user to:

```
import appPage from "html-loader!../views/app.html";
```

And then I created a button on my `index.html` by injecting it with vanilla JS such as this:

```
    const startButton = document.createElement("a");
    startButton.id = "start-button";
    startButton.innerText = "Get Started";
    startButton.href = loginPage;
```

However, when clicking on the button I get to a new page `about:blank#blocked` and not to the page I'm actually referencing on the href tag. By inspecting the website I can see the `a` tag has the following content:

```
<a id="start-button" href="// Module
var code = &quot;<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang=\&quot;en\&quot;>\r\n\t<head>\r\n\t\t<meta charset=\&quot;UTF-8\&quot; />\r\n\t\t<meta name=\&quot;viewport\&quot; content=\&quot;width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\&quot; />\r\n\t\t<title>Todoers</title>\r\n\t</head>\r\n\t<body>\r\n\t\t<h1 class=\&quot;text-7xl font-bold\&quot;>HELLO TODOERS, LOGIN HERE</h1>\r\n\t</body>\r\n</html>\r\n&quot;;
// Exports
export default code;">Get Started</a>
```

Which is in fact the raw content of the app.html file itself. I'm not sure it should be doing that, I would guess the correct way would be to have a new `app.html` file inside the `src` folder (which is being created by webpack correctly) and then reference that file, since I will be using different bundles.

I'm extremely confused by this, any help would be appreciated. I'll leave a link to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kagunecode/todo-page) as well, which has the latest build of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a JS method window.open(URL,name,specs,replace) instead of tag , it will open a new window of your html file.

Comment: I'm still unable to achieve what I'm looking for. If I do it this way the page that opens is just ```about:blank``` without any content at all.